# Run time error when pasting shape or table from Excel to Word ( default save format related )

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, runtime-error

Have an excel script that produces a PDF file (data from excel being pasted to word and saved as PDF )
I receive a runtime error, when trying to paste something from excel to word :

> Run-time error -2147023170 (800706be) The remote procedure call failed

[image]

What is funny - whenever word app default save format is *.docx - the script crashes. It works perfectly when word app default save format is set to *.doc

I tried setting MS word default save format to *.docx with VBA, but thats only a workaround.

```
set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

set xShape = xWSc.Shapes("MOTAEK")  'a png picture from excel
xShape.Copy

With wrdApp
    .Visible = True
    Set wrdDoc = .Documents.Add(, , wdNewBlankDocument)

End With

'Set Document parameters
With wrdApp.ActiveDocument
    .PageSetup.LeftMargin = 36
    .PageSetup.RightMargin = 36 '36
    .PageSetup.BottomMargin = 32
    .PageSetup.TopMargin = 64
End With

With wrdApp.ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)

 Set wrdHRgn = .Range
 wrdHRgn.Paste
```

Comment: Something isn't quite clear. Do you mean with the following that you set the default document format to doc (IOW this is a typing error)? "I tried setting MS word default save format to *.docx with VBA"

Comment: Since the old file format is accepting the action, but the new is not, I suspect the problem could be with how the image is being stored. Are these coming in as floating images or inline images (can they be freely moved around on the page or not)? Try moving the `Collapse` line visible in the screen shot *above* the `Paste` line and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Dear @CindyMeister
1) Its a floating picture
2) playing with collapse didn't help

Comment: See if the following works; if yes, we can build on it. In Word: File/Options/Advanced, the section `Cut, copy and paste`; set `Insert/Paste picture as` to "In line with text". The picture should come in as *not* floating. Can this be saved successfully?